# Combinations of MultiIndex levels which occur in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiIndexed DataFrame like this:

```
In [2]: ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2, 3], ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'can']], names=['a', 'b', 'c'])
In [3]: data = np.arange(len(ix))
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=ix, columns=['hi'])
In [43]: df = df[~df.hi.isin([2, 3])]
In [44]: df
Out[44]: 
           hi
a b   c      
1 foo baz   0
      can   1
2 foo baz   4
      can   5
  bar baz   6
      can   7
3 foo baz   8
      can   9
  bar baz  10
      can  11
```

I'd like to know which pairs of the levels of `a` and `b` occur in the DataFrame:

```
[(1, 'foo'), (2, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'bar')]
```

I can do this using `pd.unique` and `df.index.get_level_values` but it seems kind of rubbish:

```
In [66]: pd.unique(zip(df.index.get_level_values(0), df.index.get_level_values(1)))
Out[66]: array([(1, 'foo'), (2, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'bar')], dtype=object)
```

Is there a "nice" way?

Comment: Doesn't `df.index.droplevel(2).unique()` give you what you want?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for ages and this is exactly what I needed! Thanks @EdChum :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [22]: df.reset_index().set_index(['a','b']).index.unique()
Out[22]: array([(1, 'foo'), (2, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'bar')], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity is this different from `df.index.droplevel('c').unique()`?

Comment: conceptually yes, because you are creating a new index then doing unique on that. This way you don't have to know the left out levels (e.g. say you had 10 levels, dropping the levels you don't want is 'hard'). e.g. we don't have a way to say, ``keeplevels('foo','bar')`` (btw. we *could* make ``Index.set_levels``) do this

Comment: Yes I guess that is true and important for the general case

Comment: I like this because it doesn't require any static methods (i.e. `pd.unique`)

Comment: You can do `df.reset_index(-1)` or `df.reset_index('c')` instead of `df.reset_index().set_index(['a','b'])`

Answer (score 7):

You can call `drop_level` on your multi-index and then `unique` to obtain the list you desire:

```
In [126]:    
df.index.droplevel('c').unique()

Out[126]:
array([(1, 'foo'), (2, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'bar')], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to access index columns the same way as data columns, so the problem becomes much easier if you reset the index before trying:

```
>>> dff = df.reset_index()
```

`dff` now looks like this:

```
   a    b    c  hi
0  1  foo  baz   0
1  1  foo  can   1
2  2  foo  baz   4
3  2  foo  can   5
4  2  bar  baz   6
5  2  bar  can   7
6  3  foo  baz   8
7  3  foo  can   9
8  3  bar  baz  10
9  3  bar  can  11
```

Now it's relatively simple to get the values you want. My first fumbling attempt was:

```
>>> pd.unique(zip(dff.a, dff.b))
array([(1, 'foo'), (2, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'bar')], dtype=object)
```

This is more readable, but as @LondonRob pointed out, having reset the index there is no need to to zip the columns together; you get the same result from the original table without binding the re-indexed `DataFrame` to a variable simply by using a list of column names as the index:

```
>>> pd.unique(df.reset_index()[['a', 'b']].values)
array([(1, 'foo'), (2, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'foo'), (3, 'bar')], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Though in fact I prefer @EdChum's answer

Comment: No need to `zip`. You can just do `pd.unique(df.reset_index()[['a', 'b']].values)`. This means you don't need to create a new DataFrame *and* you don't need to worry about what `zip` does.

Comment: Thanks. Could have sworn it complained when I tried that. Nice catch